# How to implement "tar cvfz xxx.tar.gz " in golang?

Tags: go, gzip, tar

I would like to decompress tar-gz file by golang.

> err := DecompressTarGz('xxx.tar.gz', '/Users/foobarbuzz/')

Answer (score 4):

Use [compress/gzip](http://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip) in combination with [archive/tar](http://golang.org/pkg/archive/tar/) or use [os/exec](http://github.com/pkg/os/exec) to call tar and gzip directly if you don't like to implement all of that in Go.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for an answer to this one too. Implemented something that should work.

```
func Decompress(targetdir string, reader io.ReadCloser) error {
    gzReader, err := gzip.NewReader(reader)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer gzReader.Close()

    tarReader := tar.NewReader(gzReader)
    for {
        header, err := tarReader.Next()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        target := path.Join(targetdir, header.Name)
        switch header.Typeflag {
        case tar.TypeDir:
            err = os.MkdirAll(target, os.FileMode(header.Mode))
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }

            setAttrs(target, header)
            break

        case tar.TypeReg:
            w, err := os.Create(target)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            _, err = io.Copy(w, tarReader)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            w.Close()

            setAttrs(target, header)
            break

        default:
            log.Printf("unsupported type: %v", header.Typeflag)
            break
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func setAttrs(target string, header *tar.Header) {
    os.Chmod(target, os.FileMode(header.Mode))
    os.Chtimes(target, header.AccessTime, header.ModTime)
}
```